# BPM Lombardi logging

Tags: log4j, websphere, business-process-management

We're running BPM 8.5.6 on WAS 8.5.5. Apps are running fine its just that in the SystemOut.log we get a lot of noise *read stack traces like "Process * from Propertie * is undefined ///stack //.

This is all application logging and I dont want that in my SystemOut.log. They're there because someone doesn't fill in a propertie in a form or tries to pick up a task wich doesn't exist anymore.

Since it's all Lombardi stacks I'm not sure if I can adjus it with log4j. 
Is this just a bug from IBM BPM or is there a solution to this problem.

Thanks, 
Kind regards,
Davy

Answer (score 0):

You can check your trace string. if it looks like this, it means you are logging everything for lombardi.

```
*=info: WLE.*=all
```

You can turn off trace by `*=info`. And in similar way you can change the level and components for less logging.

```
<components>=<level>
```

So this way you can configure your logging level for each components.

More info you can read here.
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/utrb_loglevel.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-19-6-586